# Passing two parameters to another controller with js

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

This is a button passing parameter values to another controller. It works perfectly for passing one value to the CarController but when I pass two I see it passing in the vehicle page but the breakpoint on the CarController shows that the vin_num value passed but the stock_num is null

**Passing one param**, works perfectly.
     Vehicle.js

```
$(".button").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        url: "/Cars/setD",
        data: JSON.stringify({ vin_num: this.id }),
        success: function (result) {
            window.location.href = '/Cars/Index';
        }
    });
});
```

CarController.cs

```
public JsonResult setD(string vin_num)
{
    Session["vin_num"] = vin_num;
    return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**What I tried, for passing two values.**

```
$(".button").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        url: "/Cars/setD",
        data: JSON.stringify({ vin_num: this.id, stock_num: this.id2 }),
        success: function (result) {
            window.location.href = '/Cars/Index';
        }
    });
});
```

CarController.cs

```
public JsonResult setD(string vin_num, string stock_num)
{
    Session["vin_num"] = vin_num;
    Session["stock_num"] = stock_num;
    return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: what is the error when passing two(2) variables?

Comment: `.AllowGet` why open that potential? A malicious attacker can gain access to the JSON payload through a process known as JSON Hijacking re: http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/25/json-hijacking.aspx/

Comment: There is no error, it just passes the one value and then the second is shown to be passing on the original controller but when I check on the second controller it gets the first param and the second is null

Comment: From where do you get the values of `vin_num` and `stock_num`?

Comment: are you sure this.id2 got a value when you click, this.id pretty sure he got your id but what about this.id2 what it represent from .button ?

Comment: It means that `this.id2` is `null` (which you can easily check by debugging you script - including using `console.log(this.id2);` But it could only have a value if your button had an attribute `id2="..."` which is invalid anyway. If you want to store arbitrary data in the button, use `data-id2=".."` and access it using `var id2 = $(this).data('id2');`

Comment: yes, this.id2 is returning a null. The button value vin_num is a column in a datatable. I never assigned this.id2 which is why its not working and this.id was assigned implicitly i believe. How would I use an additional column

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Route attribute:

```
[Route("api/car/{param}/{paramTwo}")]
public JsonResult GetSomething(int param, int paramTwo) {
}
```

You can find more information about Attribute Routing in the following link

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Comment: MVC 5 has the route attribute, in previous version you will have to modify the routing in the routeConfig.cs, have a look at this post https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/

Comment: What does this have to do with the question. It would make no difference at all (and the ajax call is a POST, so the routing is irrelevant)

Answer (score 0):

Create a class for the object then pass that object:

```
public class Stock
{
   string vin_num { get; set; };
   string stock_num { get; set; };
}
```

in controller:

```
public JsonResult setD(Stock stock)
{
```

and use it:

```
data: JSON.stringify(stock:{ vin_num: this.id, stock_num: this.id2 }),
```

Alternatively:

```
var mydata= {stock { vin_num: this.id, stock_num: this.id2 }};
...
data: JSON.stringify(mydata),
```

Comment: tried it and no luck, still passes null for second param

Comment: Double check the value prior to the send `console.log(this.id2)` whatever that is.  ( I question that just a bit here...)  Does `.button` have an attribute of that name (id2)?

Comment: hmm, its undefined

Comment: the controller shows it has a value but the script doesn't. any idea how I can change the this statement to make it work

Comment: Post the markup that contains the values so I can provide the proper selector or other...as I have no insight into your markup at this point and that is key here.